# Deleting an Item From an NSOrderedSet and Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm working with Core Data for a project and I'm running into some problems with deleting a Page object that has a relationship with Book object (Book object stores an NSOrderedSet that stores Page objects). I try to delete by doing this:

```
- (void) deleteFiles: (Page *)deletedPage {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *err;
    NSString *filePath = deletedPage.imageURL;
    BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&err];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Page" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageURL == %@", deletedPage.imageURL]];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *product in results) {
        NSLog(@"%@", product);
        [context deleteObject:product];
    }
    [book removeHasPagesObject: deletedPage];
    [context save:&error];

}
```

and it seems to work while the app is still running. However if I quit the app and reopen it, some of the Page objects I had supposedly deleted before are still there.

Note: Although I'm using a for each loop to delete stuff in the context, I'm only deleting one object at a time because each object has a unique imageURL value.

Note: book is a Book object that I pass into the class from segue from another class. book is a global variable in this class and is the core data object that contains the NSOrderedSet that the Page object is in.

Comment: book (iVar?) isn't nil?  What class is this function in?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that book is a Book object that I pass into the class from segue from another class. book is a global variable in this class and is the core data object that contains the NSOrderedSet that the Page object is in.

Comment: It's never nil, though?  I guess you could see if error is ever non-nil, too.  Those are minor nits to pick, though.

Comment: why would book need to be nil?

Comment: Book shouldn't ever be nil, but you'll see no error if it is.  Error should always stay nil, or there's an error.  Your code omits checking either thing, so it's worth mentioning, and checking to debug your issue.

Comment: have you defined the `book` inverse relationship on the `Page` entity as required? I would try and replace `[book removeHasPagesObject: deletedPage]` with `[context deleteObject:deletedPage]`

Comment: Yes, I also did [context deleteObject:deletedPage] in the for each loop. I don't know how to set the inverse for the relationship because in the core data relationship editor, it only give me the option "no inverse relationship".

Comment: @Alexyuiop You must define the first (with no inverse) and when defining the inverse on the other entity, set the inverse of the inverse to the original relationship. You must define them in both directions and only then set them as inverse of each other.

Comment: Alright doing that and removing [book removeHasPagesObject: deletedPage]` and only having `[context deleteObject:deletedPage]` seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This:

> seems to work while the app is still running. However if I quit the app and reopen it, some of the Page objects I had supposedly deleted before are still there.

usually happens when the context is not being saved properly. Try this:

```
NSError *savingError = nil;

if ([self.YourManagedObjectContext save:&savingError]) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully saved the context.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save the context. Error = %@", savingError);
}
```

See what you get and tell me if this solved the issue, Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey I implemented this code and I got 
`2014-05-05 22:30:32.442 Lyte[1033:60b] Failed to save the context. Error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133020.)" UserInfo=0x15fef880 {conflictList=(
    "NSMergeConflict (0x15d14fa0) for NSManagedObject (0x15d3ada0) with objectID '0x15db05d0 <x-coredata://8C5EE450-CEA4-45EB-89DB-06F28CC6642F/Page/p1>' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = 5 and old object snapshot {\n    imageURL = "p.jpeg";\n  pageNumber = 0;\n} and new cached row = {\n    imageURL = "i.jpeg";\n  pageNumber = 0;\n}",`

Comment: and also about 3 other NSMergeConflicts like the one shown above